# multiple queries in model file codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a site based on the PHP framework, CodeIgniter. I am facing a problem while fetching data from the database table `travels_detail` on a page.

The controller method:

```
function search_travel(){
    $departure= $this->input->post('departure');
    $destination= $this->input->post('destination'); 
    $data['var']= $this->Travel->search_travel($departure, $destination);
    $this->load->view('flight-list',$data);
}
```

And the model method:

```
function search_travel($departure, $destination){
    $this->db->select()->from('travels_detail')->where('departure', $departure)->where('destination', $destination);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();      
}
```

The problem is, I want to execute another query and want to get some data from another table in the same page.

For instance, I'm getting data from `travels_detail` table of `airline: arik` and I want to get the image of `arik` airline from `airlines` table.

The query should be:

```
select image from airline where airline = '$airline'
```

How do I do this in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can fetch both information of airlines and its image by simply joining two table.

The code in codeigniter could be like this:

```
function search_travel($departure, $destination){
    return $this->db
                ->select('travels_detail.airline, airlines.image')
                ->from('travels_detail')
                ->join('airlines', 'airlines.airline = travels_detail.airline')
                ->where('travels_detail.departure', $departure)
                ->where('travels_detail.destination', $destination)
                ->get()
                ->result_array();    
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is the same.

Controller:

```php
function search_travel() {
    $departure   = $this->input->post('departure');
    $destination = $this->input->post('destination'); 
    $data['var'] = $this->Travel->search_travel($departure, $destination);

    // You just add an additional call to your model, for the new query
    $airline = $this->input->post('airline'); 
    $data['whatever'] = $this->Travel->travels_detail($airline);

    $this->load->view('flight-list', $data);
}
```

Model:

```php
function travels_detail($airline) {
    return $this->db
        ->select('image')
        ->from('airlines')
        ->where('airline', $airline)
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
}
```

A few notes:

- Use separate model classes for separate tables
- Use semantic naming for your variables. `var` is not helful.